# Jackson error when sending multiple objects with jQuery AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

Went over various questions similar to this, but it seems I'm doing everything fine and still get an error in interpreting the object on server... Must be missing something. :)

Essentials: (1) client-side - jQuery (2) server-side - Spring + Jackson

I am interested in sending an object and a boolean in the body of a PUT request. The object is structured like that:

```
templateRequest: {
    template: template,
    deviceIds: deviceIds
}
```

where `template` is an object itself and `deviceIds` is an array of integers. The additional boolean is named `shouldCheck`.

Client sends the data thus:

```
$.ajax({
        url: /* the REST service url */,
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            templateRequest: {
                template: template,
                deviceIds: deviceIds
            },
            shouldCheck: shouldCheck
        }),
        complete: /* the callback function */
    });
```

The server expects this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = /* the required URL */, method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=*/*")
@ResponseBody public boolean updateTemplate(
    @RequestBody TemplateRequest templateRequest,
    @RequestBody Boolean shouldCheck) {

    /* redacted */
}
```

with the `TemplateRequest` being:

```
public class TemplateRequest {

    private AuthenticationTemplate template;
    private int[] deviceIds;

    /* redacted */
}
```

Well, so far so good (or so it seems). However, when I actually run this thing, I get the following error:

```
{"General Error":"Unrecognized field \"templateRequest\" (Class
/* TemplateRequest fully qualified name */), not marked as ignorable\n at
[Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@49720af4; line: 1, column: 21]
(through reference chain: /* TemplateRequest fully qualified name */[\"templateRequest\"])"}
```

Seems like I send the objects incorrectly. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont think you can have two `@RequestBody`

Comment: Hmmm. Life is not that easy, you mean? :) Will try moving the boolean to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a container class which will have these two classes as properties then you will have the container class in the `@RequestBody`.

**Container Class**

```
public class RequestInfo{
    private TemplateRequest templateRequest;
    private Boolean shouldCheck;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Rest controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = /* the required URL */, method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=*/*")
@ResponseBody public boolean updateTemplate(
     @RequestBody RequestInfo requestInfo){

    /* redacted */
}
```

This way you can pass any number of objects in a single `@RequestBody`.

Comment: I just switched one of the params to the URL, but your answer is a good one, so I'll accept it. Thanks!